# Invariance of Euclidean norm versus Lorentz norm

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, normed-spaces, physics

First, I want to identify the set of all linear transformations $A$ leaving the Euclidean product invariant. Let $\mathbf{u}$ be a vector:
$$
\mathbf{u}:=(x,y)
$$

$$
f(\mathbf{u})=||\mathbf{u}||=x^2+y^2=\pmatrix{x\\y}\pmatrix{x& y}=\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{u}
$$

Proof:

$$
f(A\mathbf{u})=(A\mathbf{u})^T(A\mathbf{u}) = \mathbf{u}^TA^TA\mathbf{u}
$$

Consequently, $A^TA=I$. This is the orthogonal set $O(2)$ as expected.

---

Second, I want to repeat the same but for the Lorentz product. Using the same vector, we define $||\mathbf{u}||$ as:

$$
f(\mathbf{u})=||\mathbf{u}||=x^2-y^2=\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0& -1}\pmatrix{x\\y}\pmatrix{x & y}=\eta\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{u}
$$

Proof:

$$
f(A\mathbf{u})=\eta(A\mathbf{u})^T A\mathbf{u}=\eta \mathbf{u}^TA^TA\mathbf{u}
$$

I get the same group as the previous case: $O(2)$. Why am I not getting the Lorentz transformations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix product does not makes sense. $\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0& -1}\pmatrix{x\\y}$ is a column vector, that is a $2\times 1$ matrix, and $\pmatrix{x & y}$ is a row vector, that is a $1\times 2$ matrix. Your multiplication should give a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Even for computing $A\mathbf{u}$, you get a problem, because $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix and $\mathbf{u}$ is a $1\times 2$ matrix with your notation, so you cannot do the product.

In the sequel, I will take a **column** vector : $\mathbf{u}=\pmatrix{x \cr y}$.

The right way to write your Lorentz norm is $f(\mathbf{u})=\mathbf{u}^T \ \eta \ \mathbf{u}$, where $\eta=\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0& -1}$.

Then a transformation $A$ will preserve the norm if and only if $A^T \ \eta\ A= I_2$.

PS. For the euclidean case, $f(\mathbf{u})=\mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{u}$, with the column vector $\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: I'm sorry to insist but the product of a $2\times 1$ matrix by a $1\times 2$ matrix is a $2\times 2$ matrix...if you compute your product as you wrote it, you will get $\pmatrix{ x^2 & xy \cr -yx & -y^2}$

Comment: So, there is an error in the first proof (Euclidean) as well? I am also using this product.

Comment: Mmmmh, hang on. Your u is a row vector. So in fact you just mixed up with the transpose. But still, your product, as you wrote it is wrong indeed in both cases. I will edit my answer to stick to your row notation though

Comment: With your notation, even for computing $A\mathbf{u}$, you get a problem, because $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix and $\mathbf{u}$ is a $1\times 2$ matrix with your notation, so you cannot do the product. I added few lines in my answer to show you how to proceed with a column vector $\mathbf{u}$...

Comment: So I have to select a notation based on the anticipation that I will later multiply by $A$ and therefore must pick the one which will allow me to do it, even if other notations are valid before the multiplication by $A$?

Comment: Oh. I think what happens if I define u as a row vector (instead of a column vector) is that I need to apply $A$ from the right instead of the left. So then it becomes $f(u)\to f(uA)$ instead of $f(u)\to f(Au)$.

Comment: Yes. In this case, the conditions you obtain are $AA^t=I_2$ and $A \eta A^t=I_2$ respectively.